# Find a function that finds the difference between adjacent values in a list then test against a threshold

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, average

So basically I need a function that calculates the difference between each value in a list then tests against the threshold. If the difference between two adjacent numbers are greater than the given threshold, then the average between the two numbers should be inserted into the list sequentially. If the difference is not larger than it should return the original list. Only one number at the max should be inserted.

I have

```
def test(list, Threshold):

for i in range(len(list)): 

         if abs((list[i] - list[i+1])) > Threshold : 
               ((list[i] + list[i+1])/2) 
               (list.append((list[i] + list[i+1])/2)) 
               ( list.sort()) 
         else: 
               ( list) 

Z = [1,2,4,4.5] 

test(Z,1.5) 

Z = [1,2,3.0,4,4.5]
```

This is the only scenario that works. If none exceed the threshold or if there are two multiple that do exceed it does not work. I know I'm heading in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `break` when you append the new number. Below is an edited version of your function. Also note I've adjusted the range of the for loop to prevent an index error. When comparing `list[i]` and `list[i+1]`, `i+1` can't be larger than the list size, so `i` must stop at `len(list)-1`

```
def test(list, Threshold):

    for i in range(len(list)-1):    # <-- note the change in limit

        if abs(list[i] - list[i+1]) > Threshold:
            list.append((list[i] + list[i+1])/2) 
            list.sort()
            break    # this will stop the loop
```

Tested

```
z = [1,2,4,4.5]
test(z,1.5)
z
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4.5]
```

Comment: Ok, break fixed the problem if there were was more than one greater than the threshold. The last scenario if all the numbers are less than the threshold still gets an error. Is my if statement worded incorrectly?  Z = [1,2,3,4] will return 'list index out of range'

Comment: That's why I've limited the for loop to `range(len(list-1))` note the `-1`, otherwise when it get's to the end of the list, it tries to compare to one past the end, which is where you get the error